# How to add and remove individual tkk.Treeview tags using "addtag" and "dtag"?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttkwidgets, tcltk

I have been trying to add and remove individual tags from items in a `ttk.Treeview` (`tkinter`).
I have seen references to `addtag` and `dtag` (`dtag` deletes specified tags leaving unspecified remaining)
but the only examples I can find are related to `canvas` of which I know nothing.
Try as I might I can't work out the right syntax for `addtag` and `dtag` that will work with `treeview`..!
The following is a snippet (in the context of canvas) from the book "Modern `Tkinter` for Busy Python Developers" by Mark Roseman...

"You can assign tags when creating an item using the tags item
configuration option. You can add tags later with the `addtag`
method or remove them with the `dtags` method. You can get the
list of tags for an item with the `gettags` method or return a list
of item id numbers having the given tag with the find command."

```
>>> c = Canvas(root)
>>> c.create_line(10, 10, 20, 20, tags=('firstline', 'drawing'))
1
>>> c.create_rectangle(30, 30, 40, 40, tags=('drawing'))
2
>>> c.addtag('rectangle', 'withtag', 2)
>>> c.addtag('polygon', 'withtag', 'rectangle')
>>> c.gettags(2)
('drawing', 'rectangle', 'polygon')
>>> c.dtag(2, 'polygon')
>>> c.gettags(2)
('drawing', 'rectangle')
>>> c.find_withtag('drawing')
(1, 2)
```

Here is a snippet from the `Tcl/Tk` (`tkinter` under the hood) documentation pertaining to `treeview`.

```
pathName tag bind tagName ?sequence? ?script?
pathName tag configure tagName ?option? ?value option value...?
pathName tag has tagName ?item?
pathName tag names
pathName tag add tag items
pathName tag remove tag ?items?
```

Can anyone help?

Tried...

```
tree.item(iid, addtag='special')
```

Expected to add a new tag to any existing tags
Got an error, "addtag" not recognised.

Tried...

```
tree.dtag(iid, 'special')
```

Expected to remove the tag 'special' leaving the remaining tags unchanged.
Got an error, tree has no attribute "dtag"

Comment: Btw if you are confident in your `tcl/tk` skills, you can call `tcl/tk` commands from python. That is what `tkinter` and `ttk` are essentially doing. But it would be easier if you find something in the docs (use unofficial ones because ht official ones aren't good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ttk.Treeview` does not have wrapper functions for `tag add` and `tag remove`, so you need to call those command using `tk.call` function:

- add `tag` to item with item ID `iid`

```py
tree.tk.call(tree._w, "tag", "add", tag, iid)
```

- remove `tag` from item with item ID `iid`

```py
tree.tk.call(tree._w, "tag", "remove", tag, iid)
```

---

Or you can create a custom class to have those wrapper functions:

```py
class CTreeview(ttk.Treeview):
    def tag_add(self, item, tags):
        self.tk.call(self._w, "tag", "add", tags, item)

    def tag_remove(self, item, tags):
        self.tk.call(self._w, "tag", "remove", tags, item)
```

Then you can call:

- `tree.tag_add(iid, tag)` to add `tag` to item with item ID `iid`
- `tree.tag_remove(iid, tag)` to remove `tag` from item with item ID `iid`

Note that `tree` is an instance of the custom class `CTreeview`.